# How to JsDoc multiple inheritance or mixins?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

How do I document mixins or multiple inheritance?

```
/**
 * @class Parent
 */
function Parent() {
}

Parent.prototype.parentTest = 5;

/**
 * @class Mixin
 */
function Mixin() {
}

Mixin.prototype.mixinTest = 5;

/**
 * @class Child
 * @augments Parent
 * @mixin Mixin
 */
function Child() {
}
```

Is there anything official from JsDoc? If not then how would you prefer it to be written?

Comment: Avoid multiple inheritance if possible. It can get really messy. Mainly for the maintainer.

Comment: Mixins are useful. They are like extra toolset that you can bring anywhere. They are used in ExtJS 4 and Dojo extensively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple `@augments` are actually supported by the JsDoc Toolkit (I haven't tried, but their [unit tests](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/jsdoc-toolkit/app/test.js?spec=svn820&r=787) suggest so, search for "multiple").

For Mixins you can make use of `@lends` and `@borrows`, see the examples here: http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/CookBook

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
@mixin [<MixinName>]
```

Add to any objects that get mixed into:

```
@mixes <OtherObjectPath>
```

Pulled from [documentation link](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-mixin.html):

```js
/**
 * This provides methods used for event handling. It's not meant to
 * be used directly.
 *
 * @mixin
 */
var Eventful = {
    /**
     * Register a handler function to be called whenever this event is fired.
     * @param {string} eventName - Name of the event.
     * @param {function(Object)} handler - The handler to call.
     */
    on: function(eventName, handler) {
        // code...
    },

    /**
     * Fire an event, causing all handlers for that event name to run.
     * @param {string} eventName - Name of the event.
     * @param {Object} eventData - The data provided to each handler.
     */
    fire: function(eventName, eventData) {
        // code...
    }
};


/**
 * @constructor FormButton
 * @mixes Eventful
 */
var FormButton = function() {
    // code...
};
FormButton.prototype.press = function() {
  this.fire('press', {});
}
mix(Eventful).into(FormButton.prototype);
```