# Is there an Implements or Extends annotation in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, jsdoc3

I know there is an **abstract** annotation, so I was expecting an annotation for the inverse. Ie a sub-type method that implements (or extends) and abstract method.

I can't seem to find any in the JSDoc reference.

Comment: All methods that have the same name as methods found in `@augments` (and multiple augments can be specified) are displayed as "implementing" the base methods, with links back.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843528/how-to-jsdoc-multiple-inheritance-or-mixins

Answer (score 3):

There is only the `@augments` annotation http://usejsdoc.org/tags-augments.html